# Self-hosted Signal iOS is unable to connect to internet

Tags: ios

- same issue, other person: https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-iOS/issues/2282

We've checked out the Signal-iOS repository and we're trying to make it connect to another server. We're running an instance of the server at signal.appcraft.nl. We've modified the defines in `SignalServiceKit/src/TSConstants.h` to match our server and we've changed the domains in App Transport Security Settings in `/Signal/Signal-Info.plist`

We also cloned the Android app and that one we managed to got working just fine. The iOS app seems not to be able to connect to the internet at all without a clear error. The first HTTP call that is done is `GET https://signal.appcraft.nl/v1/accounts/sms/code/<MYNUMBER>?client=ios`. When we invoke that URL using curl, we get a response (and SMS) just fine. From the app, we receive a Signal was unable to connect to the internet. Please try from another WiFi network or use mobile data. error. We also changed `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `Yes`.

We've added a breakpoint in `/Signal-iOS/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m:292`

`# /Signal-iOS/Pods/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m:292
(lldb) expr error
(NSURLError *) $3 = 0x00000001c0244800 domain: @"NSURLErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709550617`

Please advise

Comment: Hey, i am running into the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Robert, did you have any joy, building in iOS, and just connecting to the normal signal servers?  (ie, I guess using your regular signal account?)

Comment: @DrazenMokic another developer team has taken over the project. I'm not involved anymore.

Comment: @Fattie joy would not be a word I would use for describing the research of a self-hosted Signal initiative.

Comment: @Robert - thanks for that insight :/  :/